# Forcing HTTPS breaks other redirects in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How can I find out why forcing https in my htaccess file breaks other redirects specified in the same htaccess file for other domains on the same IP?

The code I'm using to force https (as recommended by the host Nexcess):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.primarysite.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works fine as forcing https, but when I put it in place, all the other redirects break. This is an example of the redirect that's breaking:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.secondarysite\.org$   [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /losangeles$   [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://support.primarysite.org/site/TR?fr_id=1234&pg=entry [L,R]
```

When the https rule is put in, those other redirects then just go to primarysite.org/page (ex secondarysite.org/losangeles goes to primarysite.org/losangeles, when it should go to that support.primarysite.org/site/TR?etc page).

**Backstory:**
I've inherited a jumbled htaccess file for my org's primary domain (primarysite.org). In this htaccess file is a bunch of redirects for a secondary site (secondarysite.org/losangeles, secondarysite.org/newyork, etc) that are supposed to redirect to a page that's on a subdomain of our primary site (support.primarysite.org/eventinfo?page=newyork, etc).

Might also be relevant to say that primarysite.org and secondarysite.org are pointing to the same IP.

The whole thing seems a little crazy for me, but if anyone has advice on how to force https without breaking all of those other redirects, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: because the second rule will capture a any URI start with /losangeles for the secondarysite.org then redirect it to http://support.whatever but here it is being http so the first rule will capture this and force it in https by the first rule for only primarysite.com

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.primarysite.org/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you! That didn't work, though. It had the same effect as not using the <IfModule> rewrite.